# How to custom style data label in Recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using React + Recharts to create a stacked bar chart,  is it possible to make data label look like the below image?

[image]

here is the complete [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rechartsstackedverticalbarchart-test-forked-jekek?file=/src/App.js)

any help pleas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another rect, working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/rechartsstackedverticalbarchart-test-forked-433bb?file=/src/App.js:554-631